# ES6 vuex import file with imports (nested imports)

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm building an webapp in VUE with VUEX. I have a base "layer" for my code with default code I need in every project so I don't have to build it again and again.

I want to have 1 file which I can import and when it is imported I want that every module is loaded, the default modules from the base layer, and the modules specific for the app/project

my directory structure:

- src

  - vendor

    - stores

      - modules

        - default module 1
        - default module 2
      - store.js (which loads the default modules)
  - stores
    - modules
    - module 1
    - module 2
    - store.js (veux store object )
    - storeloader.js (which loads the store.js and all the default modules, AND the vendor store.js which loads the vendor default modules)

**vendor/stores/store.js**

```
import { apiRoutes } from './modules/apiRoutes';
import { authorization } from './modules/authorization';
import { store } from '@/stores/storeLoader';
store.registerModule('apiRoutes', apiRoutes);
store.registerModule('authorization', authorization);
```

**stores/store.js (the app/project store, the vuex store object)**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import LocalStorage from '@/vendor/kingscode/base/LocalStorage';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true,
    state: LocalStorage.loadState('vuex_app') || {},

    /**
     * Getters.
     * (i.e. computed properties for stores)
     *
     * @see https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html
     */
    getters: {
        /**
         * Get the selected location id.
         *
         * @param state
         * @param getters
         */
        locationSelectedId: (state, getters) => () => {
            return state.location.id;
        },

        /**
         * Get the selected location id.
         *
         * @param state
         * @param getters
         */
        locationSelectedName: (state, getters) => () => {
            return state.location.name;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Mutations.
     *
     * @see https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html
     */
    mutations: {

        /**
         * Set the location object.
         *
         * @param state
         * @param location
         */
        changeLocation(state, location) {
            let newUser = state.user;
            state.user.location = location
            Vue.set(state, 'user', newUser);
            LocalStorage.saveState('vuex_app', state);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Actions.
     *
     * @see https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html
     */
    actions: {

        //
    },
});
```

**the stores/storeloader.js**

```
import { store } from './store.js';
import { cart } from './modules/cart';
store.registerModule('cart', cart);
require('@/vendor/kingscode/stores/store');
```

The problem with this code is that in some points `store` isn't recognized, and sometimes not every module is loaded with it. I'm looking for the correct way to do this, or a whole different way/idea. Perhaps what I'm doing is not allowed or possible this way.

I hope someone understands my meaning and can help me, I have searched a lot but also don't know what I'm searching for exactly, any help is appreciated.